# Correct syntax for .INPUTS/.OUTPUTS comment based help in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I plan to use PlatyPS for online documentation of our PowerShell scripts. I have a problem with the .INPUTS and .OUTPUTS syntax. The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-5.1) states:

> .INPUTS
>
> The Microsoft .NET Framework types of objects that can be piped to the
>   function or script. You can also include a description of the input
>   objects.
>
> .OUTPUTS
>
> The .NET Framework type of the objects that the cmdlet returns. You
>   can also include a description of the returned objects.

But whatever format I try to use in the comment based help, PlatyPS ends up taking every whole line as a input or output type, and there's never any description (as in Type: "[OBJECT] This a description of the type", and Description: "").

I tried to delve into PlatyPS code: it went a bit over my head, but I ended up thinking it's not even a PlatyPS thing: that's how things are output by the PowerShell parser itself.

So, question: does anyone know how to format Inputs and Outputs comment based help so that it's understood as a type THEN a description?